# Replace WooCommerce Add to Cart button

Tags: woocommerce

I need to replace WooCommerce Add to Cart button in single product page with another button to trigger a popup elementor form

I'm new to php so I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the add to cart button from single product page using the below remove_action function. You can add the below codes to the functions.php of your theme or child theme.

```
remove_action("woocommerce_single_product_summary", "woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart", 30 );
```

Then you will need to create a function where you will add the code to create the button and use add_action function to display it in the single product page.

```
function this_is_my_custom_button() {
    //Here goes the button code with the class that triggers the popup
}
add_action("woocommerce_single_product_summary", "this_is_my_custom_button", 30 );
```

Please be informed that if the remove_action code doesn't remove the add to cart button that means the theme that you are using may have overridden this hook. In that case, you will need to check the directory of your-theme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php and check the hook, function call and priority.